# Do every operation twice

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop

I would like to every function to be done twice. Arguments are in array, so it is something like this:

```
fun1(A[0]);
fun1(A[1]);

fun2(A[0]);
fun2(A[1]);

fun3(A[0]);
fun3(A[1]);
```

Is there a way to do it automatically? I cannot use

```
for(int i=0; i<2; i++)
```

cause it will be:

```
fun1(A[0]);
fun2(A[0]);
fun3(A[0]);

fun1(A[1]);
fun2(A[1]);
fun3(A[1]);
```

And order in that case matters.

Comment: Can you rewrite your functions?

Comment: No, there is no way to do this automatically. But maybe your code needs to be refactored.

Comment: Three `for` loops?

Comment: Which syntax do you like ? something like `foo({&fun1, &fun2, &fun3}, {A[0], A[1]});` ?

Comment: `for (auto f : {&func1, &func2, &func3}) { for (auto& a : {A[0], A[1]}) { f(a); } }` ?

Comment: Do the functions have the same signatures?

Comment: @Galik obviously fun1, fun2 and fun3 have the same signature, otherwise the first code snipped was not valid.

Comment: @MichaelWalz The first code snipped is just example code. So I wanted to know if the real code was strictly identical signatures. But even the example code could be mixing compatible parameter types

Comment: @MichaelWalz implicit conversions could be happening.

Comment: @MichaelWalz signature could have default values that arent present in the snippet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a C version (ignoring std namespace) for storing an array of functions, just in case you cannot use the solution provided by @CoryKramer.

```
typedef void (*PointerFunction)(int x);

void functA(int a) {
    std::cout << "functA: " << a << std::endl;
}
void functB(int b) {
    std::cout << "functB: " << b << std::endl;
}

PointerFunction functions[] = { functA, functB };

for (int func = 0; func < 2; func++) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        functions[func](i);
    }
}
```

Comment: `std::vector` predates C++11 (assuming that's what you meant by "C++0x") by a lot

Comment: I wanted to say a C version (ignoring `std` obviously). I have just edited it, thanks!

Comment: If the OP deliberately tagged C++ what is the purpose of providing a C solution?

Answer (score 5):

You can use function pointers to loop through all the functions you want to call on each of the elements in your container. For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

void fun1(int i)
{
    std::cout << "fun1: " << i << "\n";
}

void fun2(int i)
{
    std::cout << "fun2: " << i << "\n";
}

int main()
{
    using fn_t = void(*)(int);
    std::vector<fn_t> funs{&fun1, &fun2};
    std::vector<int> A = {2, 5};

    for (auto& f : funs)
    {
        for (int i : A)
        {
            f(i);
        }
    }
}
```

[Output](http://cpp.sh/7cdan)

```
fun1: 2
fun1: 5
fun2: 2
fun2: 5
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap that behaviour in a higher order function that applies a function twice and apply that function on you functions.

Using C++17 fold expressions that function could look as easy as

```
template <typename Func, typename Arr, typename... Indices>
void map_indices(Func&& f, Arr&& arr, Indices&&... is) {
  (f(arr[is]), ...);
}
```

Using C++11 or C++14 this can be implemented using recursion.

Your example would then look like

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

template <typename Func, typename Arr, typename... Indices>
void map_indices(Func&& f, Arr&& arr, Indices&&... is) {
  (f(arr[is]), ...);
}

void f1(int x) {
  std::cout << "f1 " << x << '\n';
}

void f2(int x) {
  std::cout << "f2 " << x << '\n';
}

void f3(int x) {
  std::cout << "f3 " << x << '\n';
}

int main() {
  std::array arr{1, 2, 3};
  map_indices(f1, arr, 0, 1);
  map_indices(f2, arr, 0, 1);
  map_indices(f3, arr, 0, 1);
}
```

If you know that you will only need the indices 0 and 1 `map_indices` can be simplified to

```
template <typename Func, typename Arr>
void map_indices(Func&& f, Arr&& arr) {
  f(arr[0]);
  f(arr[1]);
}
```